# Postgres.app setup for heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to install Postgres.app on my mac (lion), and running into issues.

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup.
So, as the first step I downloaded the app here: http://postgresapp.com/.
Next, I opened the documentation here:http://postgresapp.com/documentation.

When I run $ psql -h localhost, it asks for a password, and I have no idea what the password is supposed to be. Can somebody help with figuring out how to set Postgres.app as the default database for using Heroku?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no default password.  Did you just try pressing `Enter` when it asks?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the `psql` that comes built-in to Mac OS X, thanks to Apple's incredibly frustrating decision to bundle an (old) PostgreSQL on the default port and with its tools on the default PATH.

Check `psql --version` to see what you're running.

Quite likely you need to set your `PATH` so it finds the `psql` from Postgres.app . Or you can check what port Postgres.app is running on and specify a port, though if you use an old psql with a new PostgreSQL then you'll have issues with backslash commands. This is explained just a few paragraphs down in the documentation you were reading.